# Dismissing a Cupertino dialogue action Flutter

Tags: ios, dart, android-alertdialog, flutter

While dismissing a presented Cupertino alert dialogue action using the explained method my entire screen gets popped of and the alert dialogue stays on the screen. This is my code.

```
if (deviceList.isEmpty){

      var alert = new CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Alert"),
        content: new Text("There was an error signing in. Please try again."),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: const Text('Discard'),
              isDestructiveAction: true,
              onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, 'Discard'); }
          ),
          new CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
              isDefaultAction: true,
              onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'); }
          ),
        ],
      );
      showDialog(context: context, child: alert);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in what I am doing? I cant find any other solution to dismiss the alert dialogue. Please help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this case, you need to specify the `rootNavigator` to `of()` :

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop("Discard");`

Check [the implementation proposed in the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks @Serge B.

Comment: I love u for that answer :)

Comment: The link is broken since flutter.io moved to flutter.dev. Please use the link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html